# How to remember camera/mic permissions on Chrome for Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, permissions, webrtc

I'm writing a WebRTC app that is designed to be used from an Android tablet.  When you access the app, Chrome prompts you to Allow or Deny access to the camera/microphone.  According to this page (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en), if you host your app behind HTTPS, then browsers will remember the setting you chose.

This works correctly in Chrome on the desktop (Mac, Linux) but when I visit the same site in Chrome Beta for Android (v29), it prompts me to Allow/Deny each time.

How can I get Chrome Beta for Android to remember that setting so my users don't have to constantly tap the Allow button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the chromium devs, this is by design and they won't fix this, for privacy reasons.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=274022&can=1&q=webrtc%20permission&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed and the behavior on mobile with respect to remembering the user's permission is the same as on desktop from M33 for Chrome on Android.

Comment: Though this is reported as fixed, I'm still seeing the same behavior, that of Chrome forgetting microphone permissions, on an iPhone 12 running latest Chrome. The site is HTTPS, but Chrome still forgets permission each time reloading the page.