# How to get Chrome to stop asking me whether its ok to use the camera?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, camera, webrtc

I am doing some html/js/webrtc work with the webcam.  Even though I am hosting files from the web server on my machine (thus 127.0.0.1), Chrome asks me whether its ok to use the camera every time I reload the page.

How can I get it to stop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261667/how-to-remember-camera-mic-permissions-on-chrome-for-android

Comment: Similar to: http://superuser.com/questions/596378/always-allow-microphone-usage-in-google-chrome

Comment: You can't turn off that warning in Javascript. It's for the user's protection, and that would allow unscrupulous sites to turn on your camera without your knowledge.

Comment: I remember a virus circulating on some pages that successfully exploited the userMedia Camera without the need to consent to it's use. How it's done? Have no clue, think out of the box, you're the *Angry Hacker* ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use https. Chrome does not persist permissions on http and getUserMedia will stop working there soon (even though possibly not on localhost).

Alternatively, use command line flags like --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream to skip this.

Answer (score 2):

Just activate chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost. This will work like https and fix a lot of development problems, including invalid ssl certificates.